# jQuery target attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to target the following attribute value: `data-search-position`

```
<div id="result-item-1" class="search-item " data-search-position="1">
    <div class='item-colours-result'>
        <ul class='list-class'><li>1</li><ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="result-item-2" class="search-item " data-search-position="2">
    <div class='item-colours-result'>
        <ul class='list-class'><li>1</li><ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As the `data-search-position` will define how many list items it will have, I need to find out how to do that. I have the following so far but it's no good:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var colorCount = $('#result-item-1 .item-colours-result ul li');
    if (colorCount.length > 0) {
        // do something
    }

    else {
        //do something
    }

});
```

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry my bad, that was a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop over `.search_item` instead of specific `#id`, and then apply your logic. When you get the list count, set the attribute with `.attr()`

```
$('.search-item').each(function(index,item){
  var colorCount = $(item).find('.item-colours-result ul li').length;
  // alert(item.id+':'+colorCount) count by item id
  $(item).attr('data-search-position',colorCount)
})
```

See this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bh8gL15f/

Comment: How would I display the result in a div?

Comment: You could use `$("#divID").html(colorCount)` (using div id)

Comment: If I use that, it returns one number ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RS41/k8ar0bc6/4/  i implemented you code here

Comment: Use id's instead of class names https://jsfiddle.net/nz3djxvk/

Comment: Thanks F.Igor. Can you explain how I could target the different div id's instead: `<div id="result-item-1">` ?

Comment: My div has only the Id of `numberOfColours` and this approach is only targeting the first result